# Kendo grid function 'selectedKeyNames' not retrieving multiple rows

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo grid with the ability to have multiple rows selected. I'm trying to get all rows selected by using selectedKeyNames method:

```
var jsonArray = grid.selectedKeyNames();
```

This doesn't return anything.  I went to kendo's example of selectedKeyNames on there [site](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/selectedkeynames#selectedkeynames)

I removed `grid.select("tr:eq(2)");`, selected all rows and ran it. After pressing F12, I can inspect the array of rows that should be returned, which is also empty.

How do I use selectedKeyNames to get an array of the rows selected?  Or should I be using other functions?

Comment: 2018 R2 fixed a related bug: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3739

Comment: I've opened their example in Dojo and did what you've described. When calling `grid.selectedKeyNames()`, I got the two rows I've selected. Did you select the correct JavaScript context in the debugger console? I had to switch it first, otherwise it did not find the variable `grid`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yes I already set persistSelection: true.  Carsten, I'm not sure what you mean.  I opened the debugger console but what do you mean by 'correct JavaScript context'.  Which is the correct one?